# How to use style in drawable xml like shape, stoke?

Tags: android, styles

I tried to applied theme color all over app which is refer in styles. I stuck in apply color from style in drawable xml. Below way not worked, but need like that stuff.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <solid style="@style/sample" />

    <stroke
        android:width="3dip"
        style="@style/sample" />

    <corners android:radius="10dip" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="0dip"
        android:left="0dip"
        android:right="0dip"
        android:top="0dip" />

</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of setting style define a color in `color.xml` inside values folder and add to the xml as `android:color=@color/yourColor`.There is no style attribute for shape.

Comment: Ravi, I know color attribute. I am using another app to refer external project. In external project having drawable folder. When i use external project as library, i need to refer from styles in main project.

Comment: As you can see the docs you cannot add style to shape xml.Can't you refer to the color in other app instead of style?

Comment: that why i asking doubt to all !! any way to use like that.

Comment: No you cannot use a style to achieve what you want.

Comment: @ Ravi, then say any other way??

Comment: as i said you have to use your theme color instead of style.

Comment: Can u provide me example line?

Answer (score 0):

For adding color you can use `<solid android:color="@color/primary_light" />`

A working code example :

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="@color/primary_light" />
    <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#FFFFFF" />
   <corners android:radius="8dp"/>

</shape>
```

Comment: I know this way me not fresher. what i am asking is "I am using another app to refer external project. In external project having drawable folder. When i use external project as library, i need to refer from styles in main project."

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use a style for a stroke, please have a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#stroke-element).